# A certain homotopy equivalence...

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

A few friends and I have been stuck on this old qualifying question for quite some time now...

Let $D$ be the diagonal subspace of $\Bbb S^2 \times \Bbb S^2$. Show that the projection onto the first coordinate from the complement of $D$ gives a homotopy equivalence.

My question is, what exact map do I choose from $\Bbb S^2$ back to $D$ complement? Any map I choose has a hard time sending the origin anywhere nice. And how do I show that a carefully constructed map is actually homotopic to the identity map when composed with the projection?

Comment: Is $S^2$ the unit ball in your text? Because then every point is equivalent, so what do you mean by the origin?

Comment: I mean that if I attempt to map any point (x,y,z) with x=y=z back to the domain in question, I can't avoid the diagonal using any nice functions that I can think of. And yes, it is the unit ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a quite canonical map 
$$i:S^n\to X\setminus D,\quad x\mapsto (x,-x)$$
If $\text{pr}_1:X\setminus D\to S^n$ is the projection onto the first factor, then $\text{pr}_1\circ i$ is the identity on $S^n$. The other map $i\circ\text{pr}_1$ sends $(x,y)$ to $(x,-x)$. One can show that 
$$(x,y,t)\mapsto\left(x,\frac{ty+(1-t)(-x)}{||ty+(1-t)(-x)||}\right)$$ is a homotopy between $i\text{pr}_1$ and the identity (actually it is a homotopy rel $i(S^n)$ ).

Comment: You have to make sure your homotopy doesn't force you to hit x as you deform -x to y. Just take the unique arc starting at x,-x on $S^2$ hitting y and deform continuously. Then it is much more obvious than with this explicit formula.

Comment: You have to make sure two things: (1) $ty+(1-t)(-x)$ *does not meet* $0$. (2) *The normalized vector does not meet* $x$  

 You can show both at once by assuming that 
$$ty=(1-t+s)x$$ for any $0\le t\le1, 0\le s$, and then derive a contradiction. This also works for any dimension, not only $2$.